# How to determine the user who pushed to a remote repo in git using jenkins git plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitblit

I need to find the git username/email of a person who is pushing changes, consisting of different commits by different users, to a remote repository.

The push triggers a Post-Receive hook via gitblit which triggers a jenkins job, and is using a non user specific SSH authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to

1. define a gitblit user and use it for pushing the changes.
2. change my jenkins job to a parameterized one and define a parameter for the username (myuser).
3. add the username in my hook

.

```
def triggerUrl = jenkinsUrl + "/job/" + jenkinsJob + "/buildWithParameters?token=" + jenkinsToken + "&myuser=" + user.getName()
new URL(triggerUrl).getText()
```

myuser is now an enviroment variable, here as an example in an ant script :

```
<property environment="env" />
<target name="xx" description="xx">
    <echo message="${env.myuser}" />
</target>
```

Comment: Hi @Sirim I am currently facing the same issue, why did you change the build to a parameterized Jenkins build?

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins does not provide an easy way to accomplish that. I had a similar problem and it took me some time to find a suitable solution.

I ended up using a combination of the Environmental Variables of [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeaturesorigin%2Fmaster) and [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Git Plugin offers two environmental variables:

> **GIT_COMMIT** - SHA of the current
>
> **GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT** - SHA of the previous built commit from the same
> branch (the current SHA on first build in branch)

which you get every time your git Web Hook triggers the Jenkins job.

On the other hand, `git log` provides the means to get the author name and author email using the `format` command option.

Therefore, combining those two options you can get the author name and email of each commit between your previous commit which triggered the Jenkins job : *GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT* and the current commit : *GIT_COMMIT* using the `git log` command below:

```
git log $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT..$GIT_COMMIT --pretty=format:%an/%ae
```

in an Executed Shell in your Jenkins Job. Please make sure that you are in root of your git project.